# Hide Specific View when Android soft keyboard visible

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have a layout where there's two layouts on top of each other. If the keyboard is displayed I want the top layout to take the "brunt" of the resizing and keep the bottom layout unmodified if possible. Is this possible? 
Example layout below:

```
<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width = "match_parent" android:orientation = "vertical">
<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width = "match_parent"
   android:layout_weight = "1.0">
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width = "match_parent"
android:layout_weight = "1.0" android:id="@+id/important_layout">
</LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your keyboard is visible or not programmatically. Find help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737265/2694480) . Once you have detected visibility of your keyboard, you can take reference of your specific layout by it's id using `findViewById` (saying so, you need to have `id` assigned for each layout you want to play with) and `setVisibility` of it to `View.GONE`

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout_1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_weight = "1.0">
</LinearLayout>
```

In code:

```
LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_1);

if(isKeyboardVisisble) {
    layout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't necessarily want to hide the top view.  I want it to be the only view that gets resized. Right now if the keyboard pops up both views are resized equally.

Comment: so funny ... but what is the method "isKeyboardVisisble" ?